# How to search for numbers/IP/integers addresses in a continuous string using python re ? [there are no spaces]

Tags: python-3.x

Say, input is a file or a string containing text

```
"randomblahblah123iwanttosearchthis666number1.2.3.4withpython"
```

The output I need is: 123, 666, 1.2.3.4

I need a solution with regular expressions, I have tried with normal loop but that did not work for me:

```
for a in text1:
    if a in range(9): 
        print a
```

Thanks.

Comment: write your comment in the question, edit it, improve it.

Comment: What do you think – is either `a` a number or a string?

Comment: @usr2564301, you actually helped me think more. Yes, when `a` is in the `for` loop, its a string. While its in the `if`, we need to check if it is an integer in the `range(9)`, which basically means to check if it is a number. But, as `text1` is a string it is unable to get through it correctly.  I have tried the below, but I think I am missing on something :     `text1 = "randomblahblah123iwanttosearchthis666number1.2.3.4withpython"`

`for a in text1:`
     `if int(a) in range(9):`
        `print int(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and got it finally.

`s = "randomblahblah123iwanttosearchthis666number1.2.3.4withpython"`

`for i in range(len(s)):
    if re.search('[0-9]',s[i]):
        print s[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
for t in s.split():
    try:
        l.append(float(t))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This finds positiv and negative floats (e.g 1.3, -3.4, 213, -232).
I dont think it works for "1.2.3.4"

Comment: Appreciate the help, but my string/file does not have spaces in between (so cannot split). 
s = "helloworld123helloworld4567.9"
numlist = range(9)

for elem in s:
    print elem  <<< this line prints each char
    if elem in numlist:
        print elem  << some problem here